# Propel ORM - Many-to-many relationship with relationship type

Tags: propel

Is it possible to create an external field in relationship in Propel. The main purpose is to have a type of the relationship.

For example, we have Contacts and Opportunities. I need the relationship between Contacts and Opportunities with a type of this relationship.

Example of data:

```
contact_id   | opportunity_id   | association_type
------------------------------------------------------
<contact_id> | <opportunity_id> | <Executive Sponsor>
<contact_id> | <opportunity_id> | <Business Evaluator>
```

Is possible to implement it in Propel?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to put on hold. We welcome this sort of question, but we like to see what effort has been expended in finding a solution first. However, two "how to" questions have been asked, both have been _duplicated_ for Doctrine and Propel, and then the OP hasn't logged-on for several months. Oops!

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely possible, just add the column to your `cross_ref` table:

```
<table name="contact_opportunity" isCrossRef="true">
  <column name="contact_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true"/>
  <column name="opportunity_id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true"/>

  <!-- your new field -->
  <column name="association_type" type="VARCHAR" required="true" />

  <foreign-key foreignTable="contact">
    <reference local="contact_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="opportunity">
    <reference local="opportunity_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
</table>
```

Then you can query it like anything else:

```
$association = ContactOpportunityQuery::create()
  ->filterByContact($contact)
  ->filterByOpportunity($opportunity)
  ->findOne();
$association->getAssociationType();
```